# How can I remove "-" and Display blank from pincode?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have one XML document which has a pin code filed and value is 
"--60000". I am using pin code as a string.
now, I want to replace "-" with a blank digit from pin code in Jasper Report.

I was tried with this expression.

`(($F{pincode}==null?"":($F{pincode}.substring(0,$F{pincode}.length()-6))!="-"?"":$F{pincode}.substring(0,$F{pincode}.length()-6)))`
Is there any solution?

Comment: ``!="-"`` is not how you test strings in java. look at ``equals``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
($F{pincode}==null?"":$F{pincode}).replaceAll("-", " ")
```

EDIT:

Maybe that would make what you need:

```
(($F{pincode}==null?"":$F{pincode}).startsWith("-") ? "" : $F{pincode}.charAt(0)
```

Comment: Does it even compile?

Comment: @Nikolas did you at least try? Yes. It compiles (jasper report expression).

Comment: Since I have seen [tag:java] and method `replaceAll` I assumed it was a pure Java code. I don't know this kind of expression and it is new for me. So that's why I asked.

Comment: @ForamThakral please elaborate _"I want each digit of pin code, not the whole"_ as it is not very clear to me. You can use ``.toCharArray`` to get an array of each individual character, or the ``.charAt(i)`` to access a given single character

Comment: @spi I am using this equation ```(($F{pincode}==null? "" : $F{pincode}.substring(0,$F{pincode}.length()-6)))```
So I can get first digit of pin code which is "-". If "-" is first digit then I want to display blank.

Comment: @ForamThakral you may be looking at "startsWith" ? ``($F{pincode}==null?"":$F{pincode}).startsWith("-") ? "" : $F{pincode}``?

Comment: @spi It is work for "-". But If the first digit not "-". For Example, It is "5". It Is also display blank. In This case, it should display "5".

Comment: ```(($F{pincode}==null? "" :($F{pincode}.startsWith("-") ? "" :$F{pincode}.substring(0,$F{pincode}.length()-6))))```
Here What I am currently doing @spi

Comment: so you are doing a substring of ``length - 6`` when you have only 6 characters, and wondering why it is blank? - not sure what I can do to help...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192762/discussion-between-foram-thakral-and-spi).

Comment: @spi This is Works for me... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try with this,

if "-" is a first digit of the `$F{pincode}` then put "" with excluding first digit of `$F{pincode}`

```
$F{pincode}==null ? "" : ($F{pincode}.startsWith("-") ? (""+ $F{pincode}.substring(1)) : $F{pincode})
```

Comment: Hi! Please add some explanation to your code. Thanks. --From Review